# Unique pong paddle movement with keybindings

Tags: java

So I'm making a pong game, and I'm handling input. Currently there are two paddles on the screen, the one on the left has an Id of 1 and the other has an Id of 2. When doing keybindings I wrote the following code;

```
public class Input implements Constants
{

    private ActionMap am;
    private InputMap im;

    //--------ACTIONS--------//
    private final String MOVE_UP ="moveUp";
    private final String MOVE_UP_RELEASED ="moveUpReleased";
    private final String MOVE_DOWN ="moveDown";
    private final String MOVE_DOWN_RELEASED ="moveDownReleased";
    //--------ACTIONS--------//

    private GamePanel gp;

    public Input(Core c, GamePanel gp)
    {
        this.gp = gp;
        im = c.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        am = c.getActionMap();

        addStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, false, MOVE_UP, 1);
        addStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, true, MOVE_UP_RELEASED, 1);

        addStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, false, MOVE_DOWN, 1);
        addStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, true, MOVE_DOWN_RELEASED, 1);

        addStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, false, MOVE_UP, 2);
        addStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, true, MOVE_UP_RELEASED, 2);

        addStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, false, MOVE_DOWN, 2);
        addStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, true, MOVE_DOWN_RELEASED, 2);

    }

    public void addStroke(int key, boolean released, String action, int playerId)
    {
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key, 0, released), action);
        if(playerId == 0) //If a player Id is not provided, key command does not involve player. 
            am.put(action,  new Action(action));
        else
            am.put(action,  new Action(action, playerId));
    }

    private class Action extends AbstractAction
    {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String action;
        private int playerId;

        public Action(String action)
        {
            this.action = action;
        }

        public Action(String action, int playerId)
        {
            this.action = action;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            switch(action)
            {
            case MOVE_UP:
                gp.getPaddle(playerId).setVel(-PADDLE_VEL);
                break;
            case MOVE_UP_RELEASED:
                gp.getPaddle(playerId).setVel(0);
                break;
            case MOVE_DOWN:
                gp.getPaddle(playerId).setVel(PADDLE_VEL);
                break;
            case MOVE_DOWN_RELEASED:
                gp.getPaddle(playerId).setVel(0);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The problem with this code is that it only moves the paddle with the Id of 2, no matter if i press W or S or UP or DOWN.

The problem is purely in here, since if i remove anything with the ID of 2 it will successfully move paddle 1. If someone could help me find out why this is only moving one paddle I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Where in your `Action` are you updating the `playerId`?

Comment: @Joe c I'm not, I thought each key has its own unique instance of Action. Since I'm wrong though, could you give a basic example of how I would update the Id?

Comment: It seems like the flaw may lie in the `getPaddle` method or somewhere else that we can't see here. Can you post a complete, compilable example?

Comment: @ChrisMartin The get paddle method is as follows;
'public Paddle getPaddle(int id)
 {
  if(id == 1)
   return p1;
  else
   return p2;
 }
'

Where p1 and p2 are the paddles respectively. There's quite alot of code shared between around 8 classes and I'm leaning towards the idea that I have to update the PlayerID in the input class and that is the problem, but if no one could find an error in this class then I could post all of the code